# Azure Batch tasks integration with Azure REST API

Tags: authentication, azure-batch, azure-rest-api

We have REST WEB API hosted on Azure(OAuth2.0 in place). If I have to call the REST API from Azure Batch Tasks, I guess I need to pass some access token so API can authenticate the call from batch service. Need inputs on how to implement, please note we are using BATCH .NET SDK(not Batch management library)

Answer (score 0):

The current recommendation for authenticating with other Azure services is to give a service principal permissions for the APIs and then using a managed identity to authenticate with that service principal.

If your API only supports key based authentication then you can upload a certificate and add it to your pool. That certificate could then be used to access Azure Key Vault with the relevant keys (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/credential-access-key-vault).